# Radius of a Sphere

Tags: geometry, curves, spheres

I am implementing a Lagrange motion of Degree Six in Wolfram Matematica. The main idea is to interpolate six points. Interpolating of parameters is determined from the rotational part of the motion. I have implemented the code and i have drawn interpolation points and a curve, which is basically the main part of the Exercise. However to finish with the exercise i have to put a curve on a sphere.

So i guess that the raius of a sphere is equal to the norm of the points that i am rotation, what about the center? How do i know what is the Center of a Sphere?

If the question is not complitely clear or if you have questions please let me know. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Are all six points on the same curve? What can you tell us about the shape of the curve--is it a circular arc?

Answer (score 1):

Four points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in general position) determines a sphere, so unless your curve was on a sphere to start with (in which case just pick 4 general points and solve $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=R^2$, or if it is planar then 3 points determine a circle), it imposes way too many constraints to be put on a sphere.